# How to register event listeners in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, php-di, symfony-eventdispatcher

I'm writing a Symfony application. Means: The application has a structure of a Symfony application and uses Symfony's <strike>M</strike>VC (`symfony/http-kernel`, `symfony/routing` etc.), but it should be as framework-independent as possible. So instead of the framework's DI, I'm using [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/).

Now I've added the `symfony/event-dispatcher` component and to register a listener for all custom events.

**`services.yaml`**

```
system.event_handler:
    tags:
        - { name: system.event_handler, event: general.user_message_received, method: handle }
        - { name: system.event_handler, event: xxx.foo, method: handle }
        - { name: system.event_handler, event: yyy.foo, method: handle }
        - { name: system.event_handler, event: zzz.foo, method: handle }
```

The `system.event_handler` is defined in my PHP-DI dependencies file:

```
...
EventHandlerInterface::class => DI\factory(function(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new SystemEventHandler(
        $container->get('process_handler.xxx'),
        $container->get('process_handler.yyy'),
        $container->get('process_handler.zzz')
    );
}),
'system.event_handler' => DI\get(EventHandlerInterface::class),
...
```

Now I'm getting an error:

> **RuntimeException**
>
> The definition for "system.event_handler" has no class. If you intend
>   to inject this service dynamically at runtime, please mark it as
>   synthetic=true. If this is an abstract definition solely used by child
>   definitions, please add abstract=true, otherwise specify a class to
>   get rid of this error.

**Why? Is it wrong to use an alias at this paces?**

OK, I've replaced the alias in the `services.yaml` by the FQCN of my event handler:

```
App\Process\SystemEventHandler:
    tags:
        - { name: system.event_handler, event: general.user_message_received, method: handle }
        - { name: system.event_handler, event: xxx.foo, method: handle }
        - { name: system.event_handler, event: yyy.foo, method: handle }
        - { name: system.event_handler, event: zzz.foo, method: handle }
```

No errors anymore. But the event handler is still not get added to the `EventDispatcher`.

**How to register event listeners (defined in the PHP-DI container) in Symfony 4?**

Comment: You can look in the framework bundle for details.  With the standard container, a compiler pass pull out all the tagged event listeners and then adds them to the event dispatcher service definition using setter injection.  So when the event dispatcher is used for the first time, all the listeners get instantiated and added.  How to do this with PHP-DI?  I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

PHP-DI is called as a fallback of Symfony's container. So when an entry is not defined in Symfony, it is pulled out of PHP-DI. However I've never tried defining an entry in both containers, from my POV (as the maintainer of PHP-DI) this is not supposed to work.

Since you need to use Symfony tags, the simplest solution is to define that specific service entirely in Symfony's config (not PHP-DI).

Another lead could be to try to write a Symfony compiler pass to try and make this work, but I don't know if that is feasible. If you manage to find a good solution please report it in [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/PHP-DI/Symfony-Bridge), we could try to integrate it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem might be that I integrated PHP-DI incorrectly. I think,  I removed too much from the `services.yaml` and actually deactivated the DIC of Symfony nearly completely. E.g. I removed the part with `App\: resource: '../src/*'`. So, I have to revise the PHP-DI integration first...

Comment: The Symfony bridge is for simple scenarios honestly, if you are building something custom on top of it I think you will need to ding into Symfony's internals.

Comment: Actually it's nothing so special, what I'm trying to do. I only want to use PHP-DI with Symfony without to forgo some Symfony specific features like Symfony EventDispatcher. Sure I could simply take Symfony's DI and be happy. But PHP-DI is really a very nice DIC solution and furthermore I'd like to hold my application as framework-independent as possible. Anyway, I've started now the last attempt to get it working. Just started again from scratch to check every single step. (If it succeeds, events will work too.) Maybe you can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50101884/2019043. Thanks.